# Sugar CRM integration with Java - How to add relationship

Tags: java, sugarcrm

I'm trying to integrate Sugar CRM with one of my projects. I'm using Apache Axis as my SOAP client.

I've created the Sugar CRM client Stub classes using Apache Axis.

I'm able to login and add Leads, Opportunities, Accounts and Contacts.

But I'm unable to add a relation ship between my Account and Opportunity.

I've found following method in the SugarsoapPortType

```
port.set_relationship(session, module_name, module_id, link_field_name, related_ids, name_value_list, delete)
```

but I cannot understand the different parameters required by this method.

Most of the online documents suggests a simple way as given below

```
$result = $client->call('set_relationship',array("session"=>$session _id,array("module1"=>"Emails","module1_id"=>"<module1_id>","module2"=>"Accounts","module2_id"=> "<module2_id>")));
```

how can I achieve this using Java

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got [this](http://209.85.229.132/custom?q=cache:phqQT1ggjvQJ:www.sugarcrm.com/forums/attachment.php%3Fattachmentid%3D4139%26d%3D1234347205+%22upcoming+5.5+version+of+Sugar+CE,+Professional+and+Enterprise%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=pub-2070091971271392) after a lot of search

Example

```
New_set_relationship_list_result relationship = port.set_relationship(sessionID, "Accounts", "<account_id>", "opportunities", new String[] {"<opportunity_id>"}, null, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! this is not well documented by sugarcrm ;)